# Use RegEx to determine number of occurrences of a sequence that appear prior to another sequence

Tags: regex

Looking to parse a string like this:

AxBxCxAxBxCxAxBxCxAxBx...AxBZCx...

Where

- List item
- A is a known sequence of characters (like 'foo')
- B is a known sequence of characters (like 'bar')
- C is a known sequence of characters (like 'baz')
- x is a sequence of zero or more unknown characters not containing A, B, or C
- Z is a known sequence of characters (like 'Gorilla')

What I need to know is the number of occurrences of A that appear prior to BZC (will be 1 or more).  The B and C parts aren't extraneous, as Z may appear as part of any x.

I'm a novice with regular expressions, but this seems like just the sort of job for it.  I'd prefer to avoid a programming language implementation involving looping (like a tokenizer algorithm).

*Edit*:
After thinking about it a bit more, I realized that while Z is what I originally said I'm after, what really matters is BZC.  Given that all I need is the count of A before that, and that x will never contain A, I can define Z as the original BZC and simplify the problem thus:

Original string to be parsed:  xAxAxAx...Z

where neither A nor x contain Z, and x doesn't contain A.  Looking for the count of instances of A before Z.

Comment: I think you'll have to be more specific as to what the known characters can and cannot be.

Comment: @Anirudha regex flavors in different languages are similar enough that unless the only solution is language dependent using uncommon additions to regular expressions it should translate across.  It think it's useful to leave off a language tag as it's a language non-specific problem.  In my case, the language is javascript.

Comment: @Shmiddty To make it more straightforward, use the examples directly (foo, bar, baz), so x will not contain 'foo' or 'bar' or 'baz'.

Comment: So, wait... AxBxCxBZC matches?

Answer (score 0):

```
(A)(?=.*?Z)
```

The number of matches gives you the count.

Works [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28A%29%28%3F%3D.%2a%3FZ%29&input=AxBxCxAxBxCxAxBxCxAxBx...AxBZCxAxBxCxAxBxCxAxBx)

here you can replace A with foo and Z with Gorilla.

Answer (score 0):

```
A(?:.(?!A|B|C))*?.BZC
```

Try that.  The logic being:

```
A
```

Match A (clearly)

```
(?:.(?!A|B|C))
```

Match the match a character not followed by A, B, or C (without capturing it)  (?: ...) is a "non capturing" group, meaning your parser won't store it seperately.  and (?!...) is a negative lookahead, a zero width assertion that will check the characters ahead and ensure they don't match the regex within, without actually matching any of them.

```
*?
```

Do that an arbitrary number of times(Lazily - the shortest string that fulfills the requirement.)

```
.BZC
```

Match an arbitrary character (which won't be matched by the group because it is followed by B), then BZC

It's not the most efficient regex, but it should do the job

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

`(A(?=.*BZC))`

**Full test:**

```
var a = $('p').text();
var b = a.match(/(A(?=.*BZC))/g);

alert(b.length);
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/7vkzF/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var TextBeforeFirstZ = string.split(/Z/)[0]

var CountNumA = TextBeforeFirstZ.match(/A/g).length
```